# Javascript regEx to match spaces in string but ignore those in HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

**Example string:**

```
<div class="test">Hey </div> http://www.w3schools.com/html <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a> hello cool world
```

I need some regEx to split string by space get to result as:

```
['<div class="test">Hey </div>', 'http://www.w3schools.com/html', '<a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a>', 'hello', 'cool', 'world']
```

Already have figured out some regEx, but it matches spaces between HTML tags.

```
\s(?=[^>]*(?:<|$))
```

Comment: You should show what you've tried as well, so that we can help you find out the solution, you can't just assign task to us, thats why you are continiously getting down votes.

Comment: Thanks man)) Added on what currently stuck(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below solution.

```
var str = '<div class="test">Hey </div> http://www.w3schools.com/html <a href="http://www.w3schools.com/html/">Visit our HTML tutorial</a> hello cool world';
var pattern = /((<([^>]+)>+([^>]+)+<([^>]+)>)|\b([^><\s]+)\b)/g;
var result;

result = str.match(pattern);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Works perfectly at the first sight=)